# .NET C# implement custom OAuth token function OWIN OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I'm trying to implement my own token function and cant get it to work. the `/Token` function provided by `owin oAuth` works fine but mine does not.

I know my code is probably wrong but if someone could help I would really appreciate it.

```
public async Task<string> CustomToken() {

    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext()) {

    ApplicationUser user = context.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault();
    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(oAuthIdentity);

    return UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync("CustomLogin", user.Id).Result;
    }
}
```